# Why is WinMerge Tree View mode disabled?

Tags: winmerge, tree-view

I am using WinMerge for years as my preferred diff tool. Yesterday I updated my installation from v2.16.4.0 to v2.16.10.0 and now the Tree View mode option in the View menu is disabled (greyed out).

How can I make Tree View mode enabled again?

**UPDATE:** I downloaded previous versions of the tool to test *when* this got broken. It appears that v2.16.8.0 is functioning OK, while v2.16.9.0 is broken.

Unfortunately, this version is not provided on the WinMerge site and I had to dig it up in the [SourceForge repositories](https://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/activity/?page=0&limit=100#602fb080ef31ff51253a29cc).

Comment: I have WinMerge V2.16.10.0 64-bit here - there is no View Mode or Tree option here.   Uninstall WinMerge, restart and install it again. See if the View Mode has (a) returned or (b) vanished.

Comment: Thanks, I already switched back and forth between versions to check that he problem persists.

Comment: I researched the WinMerge Manual on Tree View but no luck here either.

Comment: Have you reported it as  bug?

Comment: I added an issue in GitHub.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, but found and shared a workaround on their GitHub page [here](https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge/issues/1567) (hope it works for others as well):

### Problem

- `View` → `TreeView` is grayed out (I made sure that `Include Subfolders` is enabled in options)

### Workaround

1. Go to `Edit` → `Options` → `Ok` (change nothing, its just a necessary stupid step)
2. `Refresh` (F5)

→ It magically works now.

NOTE: You might also want to do `View` → `Expand All Subfolders` (or `ALT → V → C`)

Answer (score 2):

For me solution was to add the command line option /r (include subfolders), then tree view is enabled from the start.

Answer (score 2):

In the initial `Select Files or Folders` dialog, make sure you check the *Include Subfolders* check-box.

@[bughunter](https://superuser.com/users/1754073/bughunter) your response jogged my memory. This is an old issue.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Quantium, welcome to SU. Yes, this the way to get the required functionality, but I think the issue does not appear in current versions of the SW.

Comment: Thanks, @ysap. You may be right. I don't remember if I unchecked that option myself.

I think it defaults to being checked, now. Anyway, I think it may be good to get it written down here for future reference.